# How to implement inter process communication ( IPC ) in Xamarin.IOS

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios

I Have created an application in [Xamarin.Forms](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/#XamarinForms) and its working fine. Due to some reason, I have to convert code into two parts so the one part is running on  Main application process and other part is running on another process. So i want to communicate both process using OS. I have achieved this in [Xamarin.Android](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/) using [android's services](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/services). I create a new service and run into a separate process using [messenger](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Messenger) in android and i have achieved what I want to achieve. But now didn't get any proper way to implement in [Xamarin.IOS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/ios/). I find some ways to implement [IPC in IOS](http://iphonedevwiki.net/index.php/IPC). Is there any sample that how we implement in c#.

Comment: Are you want to achieve communications between two different apps?

Comment: No. I want to make two processes in my app. And i want to share data between two process using OS.